# How to specify timeout intervals for WKWebView requests?

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I was wondering if there was any way to specify a timeout for every request made in a WKWebView.

For example, when I first load a url in my WKWebView, I do the following:

```
 if var URLRequest = createRequest(route: route) {
        URLRequest.timeoutInterval = 1.0
        webView.load(URLRequest)
 }
```

Note, the `1.0` is just an example Im using for a quick test.

This timeout works and is handled in my `didFailProvisionalNavigation withError`.

After handling it though and selecting another link in the webView, the `timeoutInterval` from my original request is ignored.

Is there anyway to set a `timeoutInterval` for all requests made for a WKWebView?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there anyway to set a timeoutInterval for all requests made for a WKWebView?

No. If you were using URLSession the case would be otherwise, but as things stand you will just have to attach the timeout to the request as you are doing.

Comment: "`you will just have to attach the timeout to the request as you are doing.`"  Do you know if there's a way to do this in `decidePolicyFor navigationAction` ? Or will I have to manually create requests and call `webView.load(URLforRoute)` like I did before

Comment: You can extract the URL and make a new request.